# Achartengine: 1:graph artifact 2: x-axis labeling

Tags: android, achartengine, artifact

1:
I use "achartengine" for a line chart. When i click several times on the screen i get a artifact (see image). Its like a copy of my line chart placed in the right chart side. It disappears when i click again several times on the screen. However, does anyone know how to avoid this.

2:
Is there an option to set a scale factor the the automatic x-axis labeling? I would like to keep the current automatic labeling (i get continuously data) and divide it by 10.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `renderer.setInScroll(true);`
2. `renderer.setXLabels(someValue);`

Comment: Thanks. Solution for 2. was: renderer.setXLabels(0);
if ((plotindex % 10) == 0){
xlabel = String.valueOf(MainActivity.plotindex/10);
renderer.addXTextLabel(plotindex, xlabel);
}